# Show or Hide Multiple Rows Based on Cell Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that hides rows based off of a certain cell (B2) value.

I'm having issues where sometimes my code doesn't on certain if statements but works on others. For instance, the, "Kombucha" and, "Koji" if statements don't work but the, "Sweet Fermentation" does.

Spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oN00bsQhCkb9bip-1IEAzxlMrk_VMOWtAqnMuVLWL2Q/edit?usp=sharing) and below is my code:

```
function onEdit2(e) {
var sh=e.range.getSheet();
var acid=[4, 6, 8];
if(sh.getName()=='Master' && e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart==2) {
e.source.toast(e.value);
if(e.value=="Acid") {
  sh.hideRows(12,73);
  sh.hideRows(33,52);
  sh.hideRows(53,72);
  sh.hideRows(73,84);
  sh.showRows (9,11);
}
if(e.value=="Kombucha") {
  sh.hideRows(53,72);
}
 if(e.value=="Koji") {
  sh.hideRows(12,32);
}
  if(e.value=="Sweet Fermentation") {
  sh.hideRows(12,61);
}
else{
  sh.showRows(1,32);
  sh.showRows(33,52);
  sh.showRows(53,72);
  sh.showRows(73,84);
}
if(e.value=="All"){
  sh.showRows (1,100)
   }
 }  
}
```

Thank you so much for your help. I'm very green to Javascript and would like to learn to make better spreadsheets for my company.

Comment: Your hide and show ranges appears to be overlapping so I don't understand what you trying to accomplish it doesn't make much sense to me. Perhaps you could explain what you hope to accomplish.  The first parameter in hideRows() is row number and the second is the number of rows that follow that you want to hide and same with show rows.

Comment: Why use overlapping ranges in the same if statement

Comment: I'd like to show or hide rows based on the dropdown in B2. 

So if the dropdown is, "Kombucha", I'd like to hide rows 11 and 41-84.
If it's, "Sweet Fermentation", I'd like to hide 11-72.

Each row represents a different process flow for that category so they need to uniquely show and hide different rows.

Heard on the first parameter being the row number and second is the number of rows that follow. I'll go in and edit right now.

Comment: You code is going to hide rows from 53 to 125

Comment: I think you need to reread the documentation for hideRows() and showRows()  I don't think you understand what the parameters mean

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideRows(Integer,Integer)

Comment: You code looks okay so if you get the parameters in show and hide correct I think you will have it. We can help you figure what you want.

Comment: So for the Acid portion of the code I would just need to do:
`e.source.toast(e.value);`  
    `if(e.value=="Acid") {`  
      `sh.hideRows(12, 73);`  
    `}`   

It doesn't seem to work though? I'll go take a look at the documentation again. Thank you for all of your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Part of your problems is that your sweet fermentation is showrows that your trying to hide above.

Comment: Nice job using the event object.  Not many new users understand their use

Comment: Hey Cooper, thanks for your help! I managed to get the code to work. I feel grateful for kind souls like yourself and have reached out via contact form. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast(e.value);
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.toast('cond')
    if (e.value == "Acid") {
      sh.hideRows(3, 8);
    }
    if (e.value == "Kombucha") {
      sh.hideRows(12, 10);
    }
    if (e.value == "Koji") {
      sh.hideRows(23, 10);
    }
    if (e.value == "All") {
      sh.showRows(1, 100)
    }
  }
}
```

None of these are overlapping so it's easy to see how it work.  The problem you have was that the else clause on sweet fermentation was always showing rows that you were trying to hide from above.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast(e.value);
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.toast('cond')
    if (e.value == "Acid") {
      sh.hideRows(3, 8);
    }
    if (e.value == "Kombucha") {
      sh.hideRows(12, 10);
    }
    if (e.value == "Koji") {
      sh.hideRows(23, 52);
    }
    if(e.value == "Sweet Fermentation") {
      sh.hideRows(75,25)
    } else {
      sh.showRows(75,25);
    }
    if (e.value == "All") {
      sh.showRows(1, 100)
    }
  }
}
```